# Redux state interface: An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

I’m trying to create a type definition for my component props:

```js
interface ComponentProps<MappedStateProps = AppStateStateProps> extends MappedStateProps, OtherProps {
   // ... some other props here too
}
```

MappedStateProps can either be:

- the full app state (if a `MappedStateProps` type argument is not given),
  or
- a subset of the state (if `MappedStateProps` defined - but it won’t always be defined, so in that case we want the full state to be assumed - a.k.a `AppStateStateProps`)

The error I get is: `An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.`

How can I solve this?

**Extra info:**

Example usage:

```js
const a: ComponentProps<{ foo: string }<-- only foo in our state props
```

or

```js
const b: ComponentProps  <-- full state in state props
```

where

```js
type AppStateStateProps = {
    aStr: string;
    aNum: number;
}
```

Comment: Please share reproducible example. Since `MappedStateProps` is computed value (argument) TS is unable to assure safety. In other words, you are not allowed to use generics in this place. TS shows you a friendly error message: only types with statically known properties are allowed

Comment: Hi captain, thanks for the comment. Isn't this example reproducible?

Comment: yes, it is ok now. Just like I said, you are not allowed to use  generics where TS expects statically known type

Comment: Ι understand that, I don't understand what the solution (workaround) would be.

Comment: Use type `type ComponentProps<MappedStateProps = AppStateStateProps> = MappedStateProps & OtherProps ` instead of `interface`. Let me know if it helps

Comment:   it does work.. Thank you
Please form that as an answer so that I can accept it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interface` does not allow you to extends an object with statically unknown members, but `type` does.

Please use `type` instead of `interface`:

```js
type ComponentProps<MappedStateProps = AppStateStateProps> = MappedStateProps & OtherProps
```